# on click not working in jquery 1.9.1

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have the below code for pagination, its perfectly working in jquery/1.4.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    function loading_show() {
        $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
    }

    function loading_hide() {
        $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
    }

    function loadData(page) {
        loading_show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "product_master_data.php",
            data: "page=" + page,
            success: function (msg) {
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                    loading_hide();
                    $(".data").html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    loadData(1); // For first time page load default results
    $('#container .pagination li.active').on('click', function () {
        var page = $(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page);

    });
    $('#go_btn').on('click', function () {
        var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
        var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
        if (page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages) {
            loadData(page);
        } else {
            alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and ' + no_of_pages);
            $('.goto').val("").focus();
            return false;
        }

    });
 });
</script>
```

but I recently upgraded to version jquery 1.9.1 and the below code stopped working.

```
$('#container .pagination li.active').on('click', function () {
   var page = $(this).attr('p');
   loadData(page);

});
$('#go_btn').on('click', function () {
   var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
   var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
   if (page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages) {
       loadData(page);
   } else {
       alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and ' + no_of_pages);
       $('.goto').val("").focus();
       return false;
   }

});
```

This is my html

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="loading">
    <img id='imgSpinner1' src='../xxx/pagination/pagination.gif' />
  </div>
  <div class="data"></div>
  <div class="pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know what changes required to be done to get it working.

my server side code

```
   $msg. = "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

// FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $msg. = "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
} else if ($first_btn) {
    $msg. = "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
}

// FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
    $pre = $cur_page - 1;
    $msg. = "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
} else if ($previous_btn) {
    $msg. = "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
}
for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

    if ($cur_page == $i) $msg. = "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
    else $msg. = "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1;
    $msg. = "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
} else if ($next_btn) {
    $msg. = "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
}

// TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
    $msg. = "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
} else if ($last_btn) {
    $msg. = "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
}
$goto = "<input type='text' class='goto' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
$total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>".$cur_page."</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
$msg = $msg."</ul>".$goto.$total_string."</div>"; // Content for pagination
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages or warnings? (in the Firebug console for example)

Comment: Is anything added to the page dynamically? If so you need to delegate to the closest static parent.

Comment: no I am not getting any errors. I have checked firebug and chrome console

Comment: @Anton I am fetching data from database and displaying it in div thats it..I have included that code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, delegate to document or the closest static element

```
$(document).on('click','#go_btn',function(){
//code
});
```

Comment: Using this code, and trying to get an attribute from the element that was clicked on. Using `$(this).attr("rel");` returns undefined. Is there a different method for this type of delegation?

Comment: NM - I realized that `$(this)` was the selector `$(document)` and not the item that was clicked upon.

Answer (score 4):

For dynamically added items, bind events this way.

If `.pagination` is dynamic:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.pagination li.active', function() {
// code here
});
```

If not

```
$('#container .pagination').on('click', 'li.active', function() {
// code here
});
```